# How do I check for NULL values in the following query; using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, nullable, invalidoperationexception

I am struggling to get the syntax correct for the below code; I know I need to use ?? and possibly a datatype with ?; but getting it to actually work is a different story... any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Here is my code:

```
Dim products = Nothing
Try
    products = (From p In dizzleContext.PRODUCTs
                Where p.SKU.StartsWith(feedPrefix)
                Select New PricingProduct With {.SKU = p.SKU,
                                                .UPC = p.UPC,
                                                .UnitOfSale = p.Unit_Of_Purchase,
                                                .UnitOfPurchase = p.Unit_Of_Sale,
                                                .Chocolate = p.Chocolate,
                                                .WeightOZ = p.Weight_OZ,
                                                .MAP = p.MAP}).ToList()
Catch ex As Exception
    Stop
    'TODO: Fix any errors here
    'Errors:
End Try
```

And my error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: Which one is a Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused because I added new records to my products table - with null values in the chocolate field - which is a boolean and not nullable in the code.

Given the error and it's cause, I can tell I would need to check that field for nulls; but there shouldnt be nulls in the first place so it is resolved either way.

(Sorry Andrew, I didnt see your comment till now, but it was the Chocolate Field apparently - thanks)